# Mayer-Vietoris argument to proving that sheaf hom is indeed a sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

In [About sheaf Hom](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155188/about-sheaf-hom), @ashpool says that he came up with a Mayer-Vietoris argument to proving that sheaf hom is indeed a sheaf. I would like to know what that could be.

I am also interested in any other "surprising" (that is, which are not directly checking the axioms) proofs of this fact.

Comment: A high level proof replaces $Psh(X)$ with an arbitrary presentably symmetric monoidal category $V$, together with an accessible localization functor $V\to LV$ compatible with the symmetric monoidal structure. I don't know if you're interested in that kind of "surprising" proof

Comment: @MaximeRamzi I confess that I don't know a lot of these notions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that's exactly a "Mayer-Vietoris argument" but it is the closest that I've found.

[image]

Comment: From what book is this?

Comment: @Tera those I some notes of my own. If you want, you can find them here https://perso.pages.math.cnrs.fr/users/gabriel.ribeiro/notes.html

Comment: Very nice website! I'll check out the notes. Thanks!